# How to make onchange submit for looping form in laravel 9

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

i'am new at laravel 9 and i'am trying to make an auto calculation field and submit if there is a change in the field form, i success make the auto calculation but not the submit, its only work for the first form (there is multiple form coz i do a loop).
Here is my code
`

```
@foreach($userCarts as $userCart)
    <p hidden>{{ $loop -> index }}</p>

        <div class="">
            <h5 class="mt-5">Product Name : {{ $userCart->prodName }} </h5>

            <!--Form Untuk ubah qty -->
            <form id="editQty" action="/userCart/{{$userCart->prodID}}/editQty" method="post">
                @method('put')
                @csrf

                 <!--QTY -->
                <div class="mb-3" style="width: 350px;">
                    <label for="qty" class="form-label">Qty</label>
                    <input type="number" name="qty" class="form-control" value="{{$userCart->qty}}" id="qty{{$loop->index}}" 
                    onchange="hitungTotal({{$userCart->prodPrice}},'qty{{$loop->index}}', 'totalPrice{{$loop->index}}')"
                    min="1" max="999">
                </div>

                <!-- Harga -->
                <div class="mb-3" style="width: 350px;">
                    <label for="price" class="form-label">Price</label>
                    <input type="number" name="price" class="form-control" value="{{$userCart->prodPrice}}" id="price{{$loop->index}}" readonly>
                </div>

                <!-- Total Price -->
                <div class="mb-3" style="width: 350px;">
                    <label for="totalPrice" class="form-label">Total Price</label>
                    <input type="number" name="totalPrice" class="form-control" value="{{$userCart->qty * $userCart->prodPrice}}" id="totalPrice{{$loop->index}}">
                </div>

                <script>
                    function hitungTotal(harga,qty,totalPrice){
                        var quantity = document.getElementById(qty).value;
                        document.getElementById(totalPrice).value = harga*quantity;
                        document.getElementById('editQty').submit();
                        console.log(harga);
                    }
                </script>

                <!-- <button type="submit">
                    <p>Save Quantity</p>
                </button> -->



            </form>

            <!-- Untuk delete from cart -->
            <form action="/userCart/{{$userCart->prodID}}/delete" method="post">
                @method('delete')
                @csrf
                <button type="submit">
                    <i class="bi bi-trash3"></i>
                </button>
            </form>

        </div>
    @endforeach
```

`
note : the button that i comment is working fine

i already try to add {{$loop->index}} for the form id and for the getElementByID in the script but didn't work.
#SorryForBadEnglish

i'am trying to make an auto calculation field and submit so i want every time user change the quantity, its will auto calculate the totalPrice (qty * price) but also change the quantity in the database.

Comment: fyi: `id`s must be unique in a document - yours aren't

Comment: (unrelated) fyi, a `<label>`s `for` attribute should point to an existing `id` attribute of an input element

Comment: Any idea how to make it uniq ? I already try to add {{$loop->index}} at the id but did not work

Comment: Your `<form id="editQty" ...` doesn't use that loop index though

Comment: actually i have tried it before but not working